# Combine a variable table with single variable in T- SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

From my `Claim` table, I get the following,

```
select min([Time]) minimumtime, terminal_id     
from Claims
where claimflag = 2
group by terminal_id
```

Output,

```
    minimumtime              terminal_id
------------------------------------------
2017-04-21 20:02:00.000          9
2017-04-21 20:01:00.000         10
```

Now, I am trying to get those values into variables like this,

```
declare @claimmintime datetime,
        @term_id_val varchar(max)

select @claimmintime = min([Time]), @term_id_val= terminal_id       
from Claims
where claimflag = 2
group by terminal_id    

select  @claimmintime [claims_came_in], @term_id_val [terminal_id_came_in]
```

I get the following,

```
    claims_came_in             terminal_id_came_in
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-04-21 20:01:00.000          *
```

I need for both ID's like this,

```
    claims_came_in             terminal_id_came_in
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-04-21 20:02:00.000             9
2017-04-21 20:01:00.000             10
```

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431341/set-variable-with-multiple-values-and-use-in), which is done using table, I tried it like this,

```
declare @term_id_val table(id int)

insert into  
      @term_id_val
select 
      distinct(terminal_id)

from  
     claims
where 
     claimflag = 2

select * from @term_id_val
```

Output,

```
id
-----
9
10
```

I can get the ids into the table. However, I need everything in the same query above where it gives `*` for ids. Now that I have a table of IDs how can I combine both table and the single variable returns min time in one query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your variable assignment method.
But for the table method, try adding one more column in table variable.

```
declare @term_id_val table(mintime datetime, id int)

insert into  
      @term_id_val
select min([Time]) minimumtime, terminal_id     
from Claims
where claimflag = 2
group by terminal_id  

select * from @term_id_val
```

Comment: Yeah, this should work. I think I was over thinking and should have had everything declared in a table